# Undefined behavior of a C function with no return type

Tags: c, undefined-behavior

So, I did some changes in this simple program for understanding purposes.
Here is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

add1(int a,int b){
  int j = a + b; // Statement-1
  int y = a - b; // Statement-2
}

void main() {
  int result = add1(5,7);
  printf("%d",result);
}
```

I know that the default return **type** of a C function is `int` and the default return **value** is `return 0` if the function is `main`, else the return value is undefined if the function does return something. I know that it is not a good practice. But here are my observations:

The return value of `add1` takes the value of the closest declared variable to the ending brace of the `add1` function i.e in my code `y`. Hence, the output is **-2**. If I comment the `statement-2` the output becomes **12**.

So, is this what we call **undefined behavior**?

Comment: "undefined behaviour" means "any behaviour which is not defined by the C standard".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Once there is undefined behavior, result may comes out to be either expected or unexpected.

#### [C faq - 11.33](http://www.c-faq.com/ansi/undef.html):

> **undefined**: Anything at all can happen; the Standard imposes no requirements. The program may fail to compile, or it may execute incorrectly (either crashing or silently generating incorrect results), or it may fortuitously do exactly what the programmer intended.

#### [C faq - 11.35](http://www.c-faq.com/ansi/experiment.html):

> A compiler may do anything it likes when faced with undefined behavior (and, within limits, with implementation-defined and unspecified behavior), including doing what you expect. It's unwise to depend on it, though.

Comment: +1 for explaining the compiler behavior when this type of situation occurs.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. §6.9.1 ¶12 of N1256 (C99) states:

> If the **`}`** that terminates a function is reached, and the value of the function call is used by the caller, the behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you are saying that your compiler appears to return the value of the last defined variable and are wondering whether that particular algorithm is what is meant by "undefined behavior."  Actually the algorithm that a particular compiler uses, if any, to set a return value, in a way, doesn't really demonstrate notion of undefined behavior.

The right way to look at things is that the language specification allows a (conforming) compiler to generate code that does *whatever it wants* to set a return value (or crash or go into an infinite loop).

The fact that you appeared to have found that your compiler does *some particular thing* is actually somewhat irrelevant.  It didn't have to do what you found it to do.  It could have done something else.

Not that anyone asked, but what you are seeing is probably a result of what generally happens in C compilers: the value returned from a function is the value that happens to be held in a particular processor register when the function exits.  It appears your compiler is targeting its computations directly into that special register.  So yeah, the fact that you are seeing what you are seeing makes sense (at least to compiler writers).

But it doesn't have to be that way.  The fact that it is that way simply *agrees with* the language requirement of undefined behavior, but it is not "what is meant by" undefined behavior.

Maybe this is just a nit-pick, but it reflects how I read the question.